# Dynamically generate javascript using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic

I need to dynamically generate and execute some javascript on change of a select box. Right now, I am using a remote php file to generate that javascript (using mysql queries).

I don't know how then to run that javascript in my main page again. I've been playing around with .getscript, but I have no idea if I am heading in the right direction. I'm very new to all of this.

Right now, I am simply using:

```
$.getScript(url.php);
```

to call my php file.

My php file produces something like:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dateStartMainChartSelect" ).datepicker({ 
        minDate: new Date(2011,03,07)),
        maxDate: +0 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your PHP to generate a function instead of a "DomReady" script, like this:

```
function updatephp() {
    $("#dateStartMainChartSelect").datepicker({ 
        minDate: new Date(2011,03,07),
        maxDate: +0 
    });
}
```

After that you can use the callback function of `getScript` to start your new function:

```
$.getScript('ajax/test.js', function() { updatephp(); });
```

Comment: Tried this, but something still isn't quite working. I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: updatephp is not defined"

Comment: Try to put the function in "$(function() { }" block ?!

Comment: Ok, so I just noticed an extra closed bracket (after 07 on line 3). Once I removed that, this worked great. Thanks.